# Constrains of UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, uialertcontroller

I make an app, where I use FirebaseAuth with a phone number. I made an UIAlertController, where I have to put verification code, which sends me Firebase to my mobile phone number:

[image: Alert Image]

Constraints are cool here, but after that, I get a new ViewController (Recaptcha verification):

[image: Recaptcha verification]

When I click to confirm, It dismisses to my confirm alert, but constraints of alert are broken:

[image]

```
func showVerificationAlert() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Verification code", message: "Please put here your verification code", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Verification code"
    }
    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { alert in
        let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: self.self.verificationId!, verificationCode:  alertController.textFields![0].text!)
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint(error)
                return
            }
            print("userSignedIn")
            animateFromRight(viewControllerToPush: MainScreenVC())
        })
    })
    let alertActionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(alertActionCancel)
    alertController.addAction(alertAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that your alert does not get dismissed for some reason. Try following:

```
func showVerificationAlert() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Verification code", message: "Please put here your verification code", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Verification code"
    }
    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { alert in
        let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: self.self.verificationId!, verificationCode:  alertController.textFields![0].text!)

        // lets try to explicitly dismiss it
        alertController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint(error)
                return
            }
            print("userSignedIn")
            animateFromRight(viewControllerToPush: MainScreenVC())
        })
    })
    let alertActionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(alertActionCancel)
    alertController.addAction(alertAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I need set up constraints, when I am coming back from RepatchaController, I need put down my code from mobile phone to alert textField and then click OK

Comment: @DavidKadlcek I don't understand what constraints.. from the screenshots it seems that the alertController doesn't get dismissed.. but there are no constraints set up in the code you provided in your question

Comment: I don't need to dismiss. Look at image number 2. After that view, I get image number 3, but i can't see textField of Alert, where i have to put my code from SMS

Comment: Before alert is show, I put down my phone number, then i get Alert and at the same time I get repatcha view, when i confirm repatcha a get back to image number 3, but i need put down my verification code, what you can see it the image number 1

Comment: @DavidKadlcek so you try to create a new alertController, and it gets displaced as shown? Or is it the old one that was presented?

Comment: I want the old one, what was presented. What you can see in the picture number 1, but if repatcha is presented and the dismiss a get alert with broken constrains, you can see in the picture number 3

Comment: @DavidKadlcek how about dismissing that alert and then, after coming back from the recaptcha, just present it again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164115/discussion-between-david-kadlcek-and-milan-nosa).